# Laravel8 VueJS Axios send array to controller

Tags: php, vue.js, axios, laravel-8

i have laravel 8 and vuejs3
i'm traying to post carts array to the controller but when i return the array from the data isn't there.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daTBE.png)

vuejs

```
 axios.post('/api/Order/create', {
        jsonData: JSON.stringify(this.carts)
        })
        .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        });
```

My controller

```
public function createCmd(Request $request){

    // dd($request);
    $data = json_decode($request->input('jsonData'));
    dd( $data);

}
}
```

Comment: share the code as txt, not img

Comment: @ericmp i share it

Comment: dd( $data); show your output

Comment: @RamilHuseynov  It is giving 500 error

Comment: okay // dd($request); uncomment  dd($request->all()); try